# Find Query result in both conditions with and without space for the same word

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my MySQL table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_bookstore` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bookstore_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `phone` text NOT NULL,
  `postal_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
)
```

Insert Query

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_bookstore` (`id`, `p_id`, `user_id`, `bookstore_name`, `phone`, `postal_code`, `address`) VALUES
(1, 0, 2, 'Bookstore 1', '1122334455', 'AZX AZX', 'Street Park, Avenue'),
(2, 0, 1, 'Bookstore 1', '1122334455', 'AZX azx', 'Street Park, Avenue'),
(3, 0, 4, 'Bookstore 3', '2233445566', 'AZX AZX', 'park Street,Avnue');
```

If I search any bookstore_name for ex. Bookstore 1 it should search both `"Bookstore 1"` and `"Bookstore1"` from the table column `bookstore_name`.
With and without space for the same word

Comment: Question unclear, please edit

Comment: Well, maybe do a query with a where condition in 2 part : `WHERE bookstore_name LIKE 'Bookstore%' AND bookstore_name LIKE '%1'` this way you will return all row with name that start by "Bookstore" and end by "1"

Comment: Why would it return 'Bookstore1'??

Comment: Not Bookstore 1 the query should return results for the bookstore name are Bookstore 1 or Bookstore1

Answer (score 2):

Tryt this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_bookstore
WHERE replace(bookstore_name, ' ', '') like '%Bookstore1%'
```